# "same JVM signature" implementing kotlin interface containing getter method

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, interface

```
interface MyInterface {
    fun getTheString(): String
}
```

```
class MyClass(var theString: String) : MyInterface {
    ...
}
```

normally when I have a variable in the constructor for a class, it creates a getter and setter for that variable. In `MyClass`, the methods `getTheString()` and `setTheString(String)` exist when not implementing `MyInterface`.

When `MyClass` implements `MyInterface`, I get the error:

Accidental override: The following declarations have the same JVM signature (getTheString()Ljava/lang/String;):

- **public final fun** (): String defined in MyClass
- **public abstract fun** getTheString(): String defined in MyClass

I also have the error: Class 'MyClass' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member **public abstract fun** getTheString(): String defined in MyInterface.

So I have a few questions:

1. Why are 2 getter methods getting generated with the same JVM signature when implementing the interface versus one getter method getting generated without implementing the interface?
2. Why is it complaining I haven't implemented a `getTheString()` method when this method is automatically generated by kotlin?
3. How can I get the getter generated by the variable to become the implementation of the method in the interface?

Comment: Have you tried `@get:JvmName("getTheString_")`?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce that resolves the error on `var theString`, but does not use the method generated by the variable as the implementation of the method within the interface

Comment: If you simply want a custom implementation of a property defined in the constructor, check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the interface is indeed in Kotlin, and you can change it, it should be

```
interface MyInterface {
    val theString: String
}
```

in the first place. Java will still see `getTheString()`, but it's nicer to both implement and use in Kotlin.

Otherwise a good option is

```
class MyClass(@set:JvmName("setTheString") var _theString: String) : MyInterface {
    override fun getTheString() = _theString
}
```

Unfortunately, it still has a duplicate getter, and you can't make only the getter private. Or

```
class MyClass(private var _theString: String) : MyInterface {
    override fun getTheString() = _theString
    fun setTheString(value: String) { 
        _theString = value
    }
}
```

Note that if the interface is in Java, `getTheString()` will be visible to Kotlin as a property.

See issues https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6653 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-19444 on the Kotlin bug tracker.

Comment: The better options are the first two, which don't seem to be related to anything in your answer. I can delete the third one, but please edit your answer yourself.